# how to fix 'ERROR: The docker version is less than v1.7. Pipeline functions requiring 'docker exec''

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline

I try to do something under docker container via Jenkins pipeline, and my jenkinsfile is as follow:

```
pipeline {
  agent { docker 'node:6.3' }
     stages {
         stage('test') {                                                                                                               
             steps {
                 npm version
             }
         }
     }
}
```

My docker version:

```
$docker version 
Client version: 1.6.2
Client API version: 1.18
Go version (client): go1.2.1
Git commit (client): 7c8fca2
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
Server version: 1.6.2
Server API version: 1.18
Go version (server): go1.2.1
Git commit (server): 7c8fca2
OS/Arch (server): linux/amd64
Is there anyone has some suggestions.
```

Then, I got the error message:

```
[Bitbucket] Notifying commit build result
[Bitbucket] Build result notified
ERROR: The docker version is less than v1.7. Pipeline functions 
requiring 'docker exec' (e.g. 'docker.inside') or SELinux labeling will not work.
Finished: FAILURE
```

Is there anyone has some suggestions? thank you~

Comment: upgrade your docker to >= v1.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After upgrading docker CE, this issue has been resolved.